# how to render individually choicefield in Django

Tags: python, django, templates, web, choicefield

I'm working on models in Django, I have a choicefield in models but I don't know rendering this manually in template, somebody can help me?

**Models:**

```
class Plantonista(models.Model): 
    FRESHMAN = 'FR'
    SOPHOMORE = 'SO'
    JUNIOR = 'JR'
    SENIOR = 'SR'
    YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES = (
        (FRESHMAN, 'Freshman'),
        (SOPHOMORE, 'Sophomore'),
        (JUNIOR, 'Junior'),
        (SENIOR, 'Senior'),
    )
    year_in_school = models.CharField(max_length=2,
                                      choices=YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES,
                                      default=FRESHMAN)
```

**Forms:**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from plantonista.models import Plantonista

class PlantonistaForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Plantonista
        exclude = ['']
```

**Template:**

```
<div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col">
    <select class="" name="{{ form.year_in_school.name }}">
        {% for field in form.year_in_school %}
            <option value="{{ field }}"></option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</div>
```

**Preview:**

[Preview html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMYIo.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just give form.field name

```
<div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col">
   <label for = {{ form.year_in_school.name }}>Year In School</label>
   {{ form.year_in_school.name }}
</div>
```

Comment: You have given models. In the forms.py you need to define the respective field with select widget. Can you post tiu form class?

Comment: Update your form to include widget. Refer https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/ then from views you can call these form. In template you can do as mentioned in my example

Comment: How? I don't know much